# Why can't I open a file for GENERIC_ALL or FILE_ALL_ACCESS using FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS?

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I'm trying to use `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` to bypass file permissions, but it doesn't work if I request `GENERIC_ALL` or the equivalent `FILE_ALL_ACCESS` as the access mask.  The `CreateFile` function returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

For example,

```
h = CreateFile(L"c:\\working\\backup-semantics-test\\xyzzy\\test.txt", 
               FILE_ALL_ACCESS, 
               FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0, 
               OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);
```

Backup and restore permissions are enabled.  (Obviously, it works if I have full permissions to the file in question; this question is about the case where I do not have permissions but do have backup and restore privilege.)

What's going wrong, and what can I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot obtain `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` access via `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`.  This appears to be a special case, although it is not obvious whether this is deliberate or not.  (Tested in Windows 7 SP1 x64.)

You can obtain all other access rights via backup semantics, including `DELETE`, so obtaining `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` is unnecessary.  Simply exclude it from the request:

```
h = CreateFile(L"c:\\working\\backup-semantics-test\\xyzzy\\test.txt", 
               FILE_ALL_ACCESS & ~FILE_DELETE_CHILD, 
               FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0, 
               OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);
```

If possible, request only those permissions that you actually need.  In my case, I was intending to call [`SetFileShortName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so I set the access mask to `GENERIC_WRITE|DELETE` as documented.

Another option is `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` but I don't recommend using this option, except during troubleshooting, because it means that you might not get the access rights that you're expecting.  It is usually best to discover the problem as soon as you open the file rather than later on when you're trying to do something with it.

Comment: I removed all granted access from the DACL of a directory and then opened it with `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` (`0x02000000`) access, with `SeBackupPrivilege` and `SeRestorePrivilege` enabled. The granted access was `0x011F01BF`, i.e. just missing `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` (`0x40`) from the file object-specific rights.

Comment: @eryksun: thanks, nice to have my observations confirmed.  In case anyone is wondering where the extra bit came from, that's `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY`, [which is determined by the process privileges rather than being part of the DACL.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: To clarify, I didn't have `SeSecurityPrivilege` enabled. `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` was granted by opening for backup intent and requesting `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` access.

Comment: @eryksun: yes, I see the same behaviour.  If you use `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` you can get `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` if you have any one of `SeSecurityPrivilege`, `SeBackupPrivilege`, or `SeRestorePrivilege` enabled.  If you don't use `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` you then you must have `SeSecurityPrivilege` enabled.  Not quite as documented, but unsurprising.